# Turn icon previews off globally in Mac OS X Snow Leopard

Tags: macos, icons, finder

When connecting to network drives (e.g. using ExpanDrive) every operation takes a long time.

I've discovered this is due to the Finder trying to render an icon preview of every music file and PDF it encounters. Over the network, this can take a long time.

I know I can turn off icon previews on a per-folder basis using the "View Options" dialog. Is it possible to change these settings globally?

Answer (score 1):

The "View Options" dialog has a button that reads "Use As Defaults"

Perhaps setting it no previews as the default is what you're after?

Comment: This button doesn't seem to be available on Snow Leopard. Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Comment: In the Finder, in a given folder, press `command j` to bring up the dialog window.  At the very bottom of it should be the button -- just checked it on Snow Leopard.